# Get dataframe when a next line is numeric

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([['ph','ro','to'],[5,5,8],[4,3,1],['ph','ro','to'],[np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
                 [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],['ph','ro','togr'],[5,5,8],['ph','gho','to'],
                 [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]],columns=['A','B','C'])
```

df

```
     A    B     C
0   ph   ro    to
1    5    5     8
2    4    3     1
3   ph   ro    to
4  NaN  NaN   NaN
5  NaN  NaN   NaN
6   ph   ro  togr
7    5    5     8
8   ph  gho    to
9  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

What I want to do is get where `df.A='ph'` and the next row in the the same column is numerique and obtain:

```
    A    B     C
0   ph   ro    to
6   ph   ro  togr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
print df[(df['A']=='ph')&(pd.to_numeric(df.A,errors='coerce').shift(-1).notnull())]
```

Output:

```
    A   B     C
0  ph  ro    to
6  ph  ro  togr
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
In [64]: mask1 = df['A'] == 'ph'

In [65]: mask2 = df['A'].astype(str).str.isdigit()

In [66]: df[:-1].loc[np.logical_and(mask1[:-1], mask2[1:])]
Out[66]: 
    A   B     C
0  ph  ro    to
6  ph  ro  togr
```